# having trouble loading XML into dropdownlist control

Tags: development, xml, dropdown, cascading-dropdown

I'm working with a GridView table and have a dropdown control inside of it. my main task here is create a cascading dropdown with a webpart I'm designing. to that end, the XML file is supposed to supply the values to it.

I have code inside the page load function which is supposed to load the XML file but it always comes up blank and I don't know why.

Here is an example of the C# code:

```
                DataSet DS = new DataSet();
                string physicalPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("../FormA/XML-FS.xml");
                string webPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("http://hsphxvsp2010t:20103/_catalogs/masterpage/XML-FS1.xml");
                DS.ReadXml(webPath);
                ddlFundingSource.DataTextField = "fsName";
                ddlFundingSource.DataValueField = "fsID";
                //ddlFundingSource.DataSource = DS.Tables[0].DefaultView;
                ddlFundingSource.DataSource = DS;
                ddlFundingSource.DataBind();
```

Have tried both path strings, to no avail as well as the XmlDataSource control which is seemingly broken altogether.

and my XML.

```
<fundingSources>
  <fundingSource>
  <fsID>1</fsID>
  <fsName>NYC</fsName>
</fundingSource>

<fundingSource>
  <fsID>2</fsID>
  <fsName>Upstate</fsName>
</fundingSource>

<fundingSource>
  <fsID>3</fsID>
  <fsName>Adirondacks</fsName>
</fundingSource>

<fundingSource>
  <fsID>4</fsID>
  <fsName>Downstate</fsName>
</fundingSource>
</fundingSources>
```

what is wrong here?

Comment: Are any errors reported?

Comment: no errors it just won't load into the dropdown list.

Answer (score 0):

If that is your complete XML, then you are missing your start tag and the XML is not well formed.

```
<fundingSources>
```